# php regex (filter?) where the regex should not be used

Tags: php, regex

Is it possible to add a "filter" with words that IF found, the regex does not split the words? - Wow i hope my english makes sense :)

Let me illustrated..

This is my current regex to split strings such as: TheStringIsSItTING Together

```
$taglist=preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/','$1 $2', $taglist);
```

With the example string the regex produces: The String Is SIt TING

I would like to have a filter, where i could put in SItTING so that the regex does not split that word up.

Please let me know if my explanation was not good enough, i am battling with my english still :)

Oh, and thanks for a GREAT community!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really check if you're in the middle of a word without manually breaking apart that word with [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) as @stema has done. To have a list of exclusions, you'd have to do it a bit more programmatically.

```
$taglist = 'TheStringIsNowCurrentlySItTING';
$excludeList = array(
    'SItTING',
    'StringIs',
);

$exclusions = implode('|', $excludeList);
$tagArr = preg_split("/($exclusions)/", $taglist, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
foreach ($tagArr as &$token) {
    if (!in_array($token, $excludeList)) {
        $token = preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', '$1 $2', $token);
    }
}
$taglist = implode(' ', $tagArr);
```

1. Break it apart on your excluded terms.
2. Put spaces only in the terms that aren't excluded.
3. Glue everything back together with spaces.

Comment: works perfectly for my needs! did not think of doing it the more programmatic way. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this

```
([a-z])(?<!Slt)(?!TING)([A-Z])
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v61i)

This part `(?<!Slt)(?!TING)` is a combination of a negative lookbehind and a negative lookahead. They check at this position between the lower case letter and the uppercase letter that there is not "Slt" on the left OR "TING" on the right.

But be careful it will also not match

> TheStringIsSItFOO ==> The String Is SItFOO
>   TheStringIsFooTING ==> The String Is FooTING

the letters are not splitted as soon as one of the lookarounds fail.

See [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v61r)